# How to sort 400 mil. integers, where each one is repeated at most 2 times?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bit-manipulation

Given 400 million 32-bit integers, where each individual integer is repeated at most two time, how can you sort them?

This in an interview questions. I proposed using a counting table with 2^32 entries -- each possible value has an entry, and each entry takes 2 bits. One would just go through the integers and set bits in the corresponding entry as needed.

The interviewer further asked what if the set/clear-bit operation is really expensive, say, takes 1ms. I didn't have a great answer to that. I considered using 11 instead 10 to represent 2 -- so that when increasing the occurrence from 1 to 2, one only needs to set another bit instead of having to set one bit/clear one bit. That does not seem like the answer the interviewer is looking for.

Do you have a more efficient solution?

Comment: this is not really a programming, more of a computer science question. Might make more sense to ask this on programmers.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: How does _hash_ help in iterating the gap between {0, 1, 3000000000,3000000001, ... } ? And how do you know that your 400M entry hash table is (relatively) collision free? I would consider this as name dropping.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen My mistake. I meant a counting table with 2^32 entries, basically each possible value has an entry

Comment: what was the expected complexity ?

Comment: you can set and clear bits with addition and subtraction.  If those operations are really slow then there's not too much you can do fast.  Your answer was good, but it sounds like the interviewer was trying to steer you in a different direction.  There are various possibilities so it's hard to guess what he wanted.  Maybe a radix sort.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm inclined to say it's **more** on topic here on [so] than it would be on Programmers (or CS) (but it might work on any one of the 3).

Comment: I'm not sure having (every implementation of) the set/clear-bit operation be really expensive allows for **any** efficient approach, because that would make anything (I can think of right now) slow (even swapping elements involves setting bits). Maybe they wanted to discuss different implementations of setting bits, maybe they didn't really think that through (or consider the practicality of that) or maybe they just wanted you to argue that there can't be a more efficient approach (or something about parallelisation) - we can't know which one is true.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this question is a poor fit over there, see [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260) Please abstain of recommending sites your not familiar with (you even got the site name wrong)

Comment: @gnat didn't mean to offend. First of all, notice my careful wording "might make more sense"; not "go and ask there"; then: this is an abstract algorithm design, and not an applied question. I did not mean to imply that this question, unchanged, would make a good fit there. A "my approach to that problem question would be {details}, but the counterarguments I got were {details}" centric question would imho be not the worst fit for SE.SE. Yes, "I got in an interview and the interviewer wasn't happy" is a bad fit for practically any Q&A site.

Comment: @gnat frankly, OP has now changed the focus of the question in the comment from sorting to counting and didn't even change the title. So this question is actually unclear (or mystifying the actual question) until they change that (... VTC).

Comment: To propose efficient solution optimization criteria has to be defined first. Do we optimize memory or performance?

Comment: If set/clear is "really expensive" you could ask why one would buy such a hardware. This is a ridiculous assumption.

Answer (score 0):

create two bit sets having 400 mn bits

set each bit of the first one, if you find the bit is set and the number is avbl again, set it in the second one

finally read the first one, if its set, check the second one and print in the order

example

Bitset1 :  10001100
Bitset2:   00001000

final value : 1,5,5,6

Answer (score 0):

RadixSort should give you O(wN) where w=9 (maximum length of a number), beating the usual O(NlogN) where log(400.000) = 19

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: (Should work. Does it make a difference that numbers a neither *unique* nor *repeated more than 2 times*?) `log(400.000) = 19` - concrete number are immaterial regarding asymptotic analysis & results thereof, missing an order of magnitude or not.

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that for a comparison you usually don't need to check more than a few bits when the population is evenly distributed.